# SQL Help : Counting latest status of each sales

Tags: sql, asp-classic, count, ms-access-2007

I have tbl_sActivity that looks like this:

> act_id  | Client_id | act_status | user_id  | act_date 
>   1          |       7       |      warm    |     1           | 19/7/12 
>   2         |      7       |      dealed  |     1       | 30/7/12
>   3         |      8       |      hot        |     1       | 6/8/12
>   4         |      5       |      cold       |    22      | 7/8/12
>   5         |      6       |      cold       |     1       | 16/7/12
>   6         |      6       |      warm     |     1       | 18/7/12
>   7         |      6       |      dealed   |     1       | 7/8/12

I want to count act_status of each user_id's clients from their latest status. The output should come out like this

> user_id | act_status  | Count(act_status)
>     1           |    dealed    |    2
>     1           |      hot        |    1
>     22         |     cold       |     1

but what i can do was only to display their latest activity with no feature. So please kindly help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: i'm using MS Access 07 with classic asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt get your logic, the simples query would be something like this:

```
select user_id, act_status, count(act_Status)
from your_table
group by user_id, act_status
```

but why doesnt it have the "cold" on user 1 on your expected output?

EDIT:

```
select user_id, act_status, count(act_Status)
from your_table
where act_date in (
    select  max(act_date)
    from your_table
    group by Client_id
)
group by user_id, act_status
```

Comment: no "cold" status on user 1  because the latest status of Client_id(6) is "Dealed" on 7/8/12. I'm only need the latest status of each client_id.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT act_status,
       user_id,
       Count(act_id) AS idcount
FROM   (SELECT a.act_id,
               a.act_status,
               a.user_id
        FROM   tbl_sActivity AS a
        WHERE  a.act_id  IN (SELECT TOP 1 act_id
                                   FROM   tbl_sActivity b
                                   WHERE  a.client_id = b.client_id
                                          AND a.user_id = b.user_id
                                   ORDER  BY act_date DESC) ) As x
GROUP  BY act_status,
          user_id
```

Comment: sorry.. it said it cannot find the input table or query 'stat'

Comment: Your table name was not clear, so I missed it and put "stat" is in place of the table name tbl_sActivity, I have edited.